# how to get number of method in class?

Tags: c++

I want to get total value about c++ class method.

for example,

```
#include <iostream>
class foo
{
    void bar() {}
    void bar2() {}
    void bar3() {}

    int getTotalMethod() { ?????? }
}

int main()
{
    foo a;
    std::cout << a.getTotalMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

expect result is 4.

because, foo have method bar, bar2, bar3. total count is 4.

how can I do?

respectfully,

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to know the number of methods?  This may turn into an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: There is no native reflection in C++.

Comment: You can't do it from within the program itself, you need some external tool that can analyze the source code.

Comment: Btw; `class foo` has *4* user defined member functions: `bar`, `bar2`, `bar3` & `getTotalMethod`. But the class also has a number of compiler generated functions. So, if this was possible (which it isn't easily), I certainly wouldn't expect 3 as the answer.

Comment: Impossible with just standard-compliant portable C++. Boost and its metaprogramming libraries **possibly** may be of some limited help here, but only after the classes to support "reflectionish" features are adapted accordingly. See Boost::hana, Boost::describe and Boost::fusion for instance (from the top of my head, maybe there are better tools for that). But the main question should be: why is that even needed?

Comment: Sounds like you need an interface and proper versioning

Comment: @user3416447 Why exactly would you have to "check changes always"? As PaulMcKenzie pointed out, this seems to be a XY problem. Please describe *the actual problem* you are having. If it's about "recompile if code changed", that's a matter of the build system (e.g. Makefile). If it's about "I need to check if I need to change something in my code", that's a matter of communication not solved by counting methods. What is this actually about? Please be more specific.

Comment: Do you want to count constructors/destructors as well or just methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
int getTotalMethod() { return 4; }
```

---

Above lies a troll answer, obviously. The proper answer is that C++ does not provide Reflection. You need to find another solution to your need.

I'm guessing counting a class' member-functions isn't a feature of your program, rather an internal need, an XY problem.

Ask yourself what is the actual feature you want, what actual behaviour your program must exhibit. There will be plenty other solutions than reflection. I guarantee it.

Comment: thank you! I wanted to know that keyword "Reflection"!!!

Comment: @user3416447 more important than reflection is your design approach. Asking this question strongly hints at a significant design flaw or misunderstanding. I would be very interested in you asking a new question where you properly explain what your actual goal is and where you're failing.